# Create new column to label variables based on the value in an existing column

Tags: r, dplyr

The dataset I have contains 30k+ products, I am trying to add a new column to categorise these products based on their `subCategory_id`.

I need 4 labels, "Premium", "Base", "Other", "New".

this is what the datased looks like, just the head.

```
product_id product_origin product_price subCategory_id    GBP
          1      Australia    0.36154597              1 371.31
          2            USA    0.14425684              1 148.15
          3            USA    0.09020571              1  92.64
          5            USA    0.35793051              1 367.59
          6            USA    0.19523482              1 200.51
```

The dataset is called `random`. I have tried this as the category ID's arent in order but I have had no luck.

```
random %>%
    mutate(ifelse(subCategory_id %in% c(1:12, 16, 67:71, 73,74, 78,79, 82, 85:89, 91:104), "Premium", 
          ifelse(subCategory_id %in% c(19:21, 35, 56,57,61), "Base",
          ifelse(subCategory_id %in% c(13:15, 17, 18, 22:28, 30:33),"New"))))
```

Any help will be highly appreciated!!!

Comment: Instead of this, you can create a key/val dataset and join with the original

Comment: you are missing an argument... `ifelse(........., "New", "Other")`

Comment: What do you want to name your new column?

Comment: @AndrewBrēza the naming isnt that important to me, something like category_type

Answer (score 2):

We can use a key/value list and then join

```
keyVal <- list(Premium= c(1:12, 16, 67:71, 73,74, 78,79, 82, 85:89, 91:104),  
          Base = c(19:21, 35, 56,57,61), 
          New = c(13:15, 17, 18, 22:28, 30:33))

library(dplyr)
random %>% 
       left_join(., stack(keyVal), by = c(subCategory_id = "values"))
```

Answer (score 1):

you could try something simple like this?

```
random$productcategory <- ""
random$productcategory[random$subCategory_id %in% c(1:12, 16, 67:71, 73,74, 78,79, 82, 85:89, 91:104)] <- "Premium"
```

Answer (score 1):

The newest version of `dplyr` has a function called `case_when`. I think it's a better solution for your problem:

```
library(dplyr)

random <- random %>% 
   mutate(label = case_when(
      .$subCategory_id %in% c(1:12, 16, 67:71, 73,74, 78,79, 82, 85:89, 91:104) ~ "Premium",  
      .$subCategory_id %in% c(19:21, 35, 56,57,61) ~ "Base",
      .$subCategory_id %in% c(13:15, 17, 18, 22:28, 30:33) ~ "New"
   ))
```

If you install the lastest version from GitHub using the command `devtools::install_github("hadley/dplyr")`, you don't have to use `.$` before the variable name.